# Diferença de tempo na execução da mesma query entre PHP e PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, desempenho, phpmyadmin

Estou tentando melhorar a performance de minhas paginas para melhorar a experiencia do usuário, mas, não estou conseguindo identificar o problema.

Segundo o Google, é recomendável que as paginas respondam em menos de 0,4 segundos, porem, só a conexão com o banco de dados, esta levando 0,41 segundos. Sendo por mysql_connect ou mysqli_connect

Além disso, a mesma query que executo para montar um menu, no PHP demora em média 0,14 mas no phpMyAdmin demora apenas 0,0009 conforme mostra na execução

> A mostrar registos de 0 - 24 (35 total, O Query demorou 0.0009 sec)

Criei uma pagina vazia, apenas com a conexão e a query para medir os tempos

```
http://omenorpreco.com/teste.php
```

Alguém tem ideia **como posso diminuir o tempo para fazer a conexão**, e, diminuir o tempo da query para **ficar igual o PHPMyAdmin**?

**UPDATE:**

```
//PHP
    $sql = "select cd_categoria, linha, slug, cd_categoria_site, qtd from ( SELECT cd_categoria, if (menu.cd_categoria_pai=0,menu.nm_categoria,concat((select nm_categoria from tb_st_category where cd_categoria = menu.cd_categoria_pai),';',nm_categoria)) as linha , if (menu.cd_categoria_pai=0,menu.nm_slug,concat((select nm_slug from tb_st_category where cd_categoria = menu.cd_categoria_pai),'/',menu.nm_slug)) as slug , cd_categoria as cd_categoria_site , 0 as qtd FROM tb_st_category menu where cd_categoria_pai = 0 ) as a order by linha";
    $pagespeed = microtime_float();
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
    echo "Query Time:".number_format(microtime_float()-$pagespeed, 2, ',', '')."<br>";
```

Meu servidor SQL é Windows (WAMP)

Ja inclui a variável skip-name-resolve no arquivo de configuração do WAMP

A conexão é remota, feita através do IP, e não do nome do servidor

Comment: Isso é query ou isso é diferença do php? Mostre como fez o seu código php de teste. Todavia acho que esta confundindo.

Comment: Atualizei o post com os dados do PHP (só não coloquei o código da conexão com o banco, mas é mysqli (já tentei com mysql também)

Answer (score 3):

Esse teste de performance é do PHP e não da query, assim vai dar resultados diferentes sempre, pra depurar uma query você pode usar o `set profiling=1;`

```
mysql> set profiling=1;
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT ...
mysql> SELECT ...
mysql> ALTER ...
mysql> show profiles;
+----------+------------+-------------------------
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query
+----------+------------+-------------------------
|        1 | 0.00036500 | EXPLAIN SELECT sbvi.id a
|        2 | 0.00432700 | SELECT sbvi.id as sbvi_i
|        3 | 2.83206100 | alter table sbvi drop in
|        4 | 0.00047500 | explain SELECT sbvi.id a
|        5 | 0.00367100 | SELECT sbvi.id as sbvi_i
+----------+------------+-------------------------
```

Documentação: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profile.html

Comment: Ola Guilherme,

Usei o comando que me indicou e aparentemente, o resultado é inferior
1 - 0.00067650 - select cd_categoria, linha, slug, cd_categoria_sit...

Comment: Queria entender porque pelo PHP é mais demorado mesmo? Porque tem o trafego de rede? E pelo PHPMyAdmin é direto na mesma maquina o servidor PHP e o banco?

Comment: @RodrigoMendes o phpmyadmin é uma ferramenta escrita em php, no entanto o resultados deles de tempo deve ser com o profile e nada tem haver com o PHP, como no exemplo, já o teste que você criou é usando funções PHP, ou seja um teste não tem nada haver com o outro, não tem porque comparar ambos.

Comment: Ok Guilherme, agora entendi o que estavam querendo dizer. Mas existe uma forma de eu diminuir este tempo no php? Pois através do Google speed test, minha pagina esta demorando 2 ou 3 segundos para carregar, mas as querys ja estão super otimizadas. Como teste, coloquei umas variáveis de tempo de execução de cada query no rodape http://omenorpreco.com/produto/oculos-oakley-conquest-polarizado-bronze. O recomendado pelo google é o servidor responder em menos de 200ms. 

Tentei colocar o comando flush(); apos o </head> para minimizar o tempo, mas nao adiantou nada.

Comment: Acredito que a melhor solução é usar cache e CDN, assim como usar servidores mais robustos e com maior largura de banda. Acredito que o problema possa está na configuração do _NGINX_ ou do _Apache_ (não sei qual usa). Claro, utilize também uma versão atualizada do PHP, geralmente versões recentes são mais rapidas do que anteriores. :P

Comment: Utilizo o servidor godaddy, consigo mexer nestas configuracoes desta forma? Cache eu ja utilizo, mas CDN? É um serviço pago? Desculpa nao conheco.