# PHP Mysql performance de conexao em servidor remoto

Tags: php, mysql, servidor, google, conexão

Estou a todo custo tentando melhorar o tempo de carregamento de minhas paginas, porem estou sofrendo com um gargalo. A conexão entre o servidor web(godaddy) e meu servidor de banco de dados(local com ip dedicado)

Fiz um teste com uma pagina simples que apenas conecta no banco de dados local, e executa um comando simples (select now();)

Essa pagina quando esta no servidor godaddy, apontando pro meu IP fixo e minha base, demora:
Connection Time:0,4183s
Query Time:0,1390s

Porem, quando coloco essa pagina PHP no meu servidor local, os tempos são:

Connection Time:0,0011
Query Time:0,0003
Usando o IP externo como conexão e não local host ou 127.0.0.1

Parece pouco tempo, mas quando tenho muitas queries para montar uma pagina, a pagina demora 2, 3 segundos no total, o que para o google, é um tempo muito alto.

Como posso reduzir este tempo do godaddy para conectar no meu servidor?
É alguma configuração de rede do meu servidor local?

obs.: Minha base de dados tem 60GB, por isso não posso usar o servidor MySQL do godaddy, eles permitem no máximo 1GB

Obrigado

Comment: Relacionada: [Diferença de tempo na execução da mesma query entre PHP e PHPMYADMIN](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141425/diferen%C3%A7a-de-tempo-na-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-mesma-query-entre-php-e-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Supondo que seu servidor esteja bem configurado, é questão de por um link melhor de internet nele. Se for link caseiro tipo ADSL, etc, nao vai ter como competir com um link dedicado (independente de ser IP fixo ou não, o link tem que ser bom).

Comment: O link de internet do servidor de banco é de 50MB fixo (de envio e recebimento), é pouco? Nao seria alguma outra configuraçao? Como firewall ou alguma restricao de configuracao? Este servidor é WINDOWS e utilizo o WAMP,  mas apenas uso a base, nao uso o apache

Comment: Se os 50 funcionam bem mesmo, pode ser problema na configuração do servidor. Firewall pode interferir, mas só se tiver alguma regra muito absurda e complexa.